# how to use mbedtls_pk_verify to verify signature

Tags: c, embedded

How to use this function.

```
int mbedtls_pk_verify(mbedtls_pk_context *  ctx, mbedtls_md_type_t md_alg, const unsigned char * hash, size_t hash_len, const unsigned char * sig, size_t sig_len)
```

So by calling the function like this `mbedtls_pk_verify(&public_key_context, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA1, md, sizeof(md), signature, signature_lenght)` how should I initialize md and how do I know what it is?

Comment: It guess hash should be the message hashed with same algorithm that the signature that was generated from the message. Maybe read [Why hash the message before signing it with RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12768/why-hash-the-message-before-signing-it-with-rsa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`md` is the `message digest` (usually a hash value).

To verify a signature, you have to feed the message through the *same hash algorithm* that was used when creating the signature. If the signature was created using SHA1, then you have to calculate the SHA1 hash value for the message you want to verify first. Then you pass this value together with its length (20 bytes in this case) to the function.

You can use the mbedtls library itself to calculate the message digest:

```
// Get the message digest info structure for SHA1
const mbedtls_md_info_t *mdinfo = mbedtls_md_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_MD_SHA1);
unsigned char *md = malloc(mdinfo->size);
// Calculate the message digest for the data
mbedtls_md(mdinfo, data, datalen, md);

// Now verify the signature for the given hash of the data
int st = mbedtls_pk_verify(&public_key_context, 
                           mdinfo->type, md, mdinfo->size,
                           signature, signature_length);
if (st != 0) {
      // Signature invalid!
} else {
      // Signature valid
}

free(md);
```

This should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks! one more question to your answer, data and datalen what is that?

Comment: @Noob14 The data for which you want to verify the signature (i.e. a message)

Comment: Okay, perfect! now it works. Thank you very much! :)